# Audio playback timing is inconsistent

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I'm still quite new to Blender and video editing but I'll do my best to provide as detailed of info as I can.

The issue I'm dealing with is I used a screen recorder to record audio for the voiceover for a video I'm making. I then went to edit out the cuts and add in still images I'd created for this video. As soon as I start adding in any images and making any cuts in the audio, the audio gets very random and will sometimes play back faster then normal, and when I pause and hit play, it will start playing several frames back, causing the audio to go out of sync with the current frame. Let's say I'm on frame 580 when I pause. When I hit play again, the sound will start playing from, say, frame 560. Another time it may start playing from frame 555 when I pause on the exact same frame, so it's very inconsistent.

I have had video-audio sync issues in the past but that was when using both the video and audio from a screen recording, and I was able to find a solution to that issue, but this time, what's baffling is that this is so inconsistent, other then that I can guarantee the sync issue will eventually start happening as soon as I start doing any edits. It does not seem to happen as long as I leave the video+audio in a single, raw, unedited cut. This also does not seem to be quite the same issue as I ran into before as the fix for that is not possible for this issue, the option for fixing that other sync issue was a setting in the video strip, which I'm not even using for this video, I just delete that part, and that setting isn't even an option in the audio properties.

I'm using Blender 2.8a and I know there is a 2.8c out now, but am not sure if this is a known bug or if it's been fixed or not, couldn't find any dev notes on the Bender.org site to see what bugs have been fixed or are waiting to be fixed.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: What is your *Sync Mode* set to?  How are you cutting and splicing your audio?  A screenshot or two would be nice, also.

Comment: I'd love to add screenshots, but that's impossible due to a bug in the image tool. I don't know what my sync mode is set to and don't know where that info is located in Blender.

Comment: As for how I'm cutting my audio, I'm using the Blender cut tool. Tried using both hard and soft cuts, both produce the same issue.

Comment: I'm unsure what bug you're referring to but you can simply Alt+PrtScreen is you're using Windows to make a screenshot.  Just paste in Paint or some other image file editor.  The Sync Mode is listed in the toolbar of the *Timeline Editor*.  The possible values are AV-Sync, Frame-Dropping, and No-Sync.  You should at the least try each of them and see if it helps.

Comment: It's a bug with the Stack community tool to add/link to images. Believe me, I've tried to post screenshots and I can't. I just get this popup that I can't do anything with, it's totally unresponsive. You can see more details on that issue here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297270/cant-upload-or-link-to-any-images-image-tool-seems-broken

Comment: It was set to "no sync" tried "av sync" and so far so good. Thanks. Hopefully this solution will stand the test when I get back to editing my video properly again tomorrow.

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  If that works for you, you should add it as the answer below so others can benefit.

Comment: I will as soon as I get another issue I'm having figured out. I was able to get through editing the video ok, but ran into issues while rendering. I think that problem may have been caused by the fact that the file was recorded at 15 FPS and I didn't notice Blender was set to render it at 30FPS. Changing that setting seems to mess up the whole file as all my audio tracks then stretch out to double their original length and overlap each other. I'll have to re-do the editing from scratch again and hopefully all goes well. When it does I'll post what I did to fix both the main issue and this one.

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to get the video edited without any problems this time. Turns out my original issue was indeed the Sync Mode setting, which needed to be in AV Sync for the audio playback timing to work. The later issue was also causes by the Rendering options being set to the wrong FPS. It was set to 30 fps when the files I was importing were recorded in 15 fps. Once I got those sorted out everything worked and I was able to create and upload the video with no further problems. Thanks for your help @bertmoog.

### Update / Note:

The "**AV Sync**" setting is now called "**Sync to Audio**".

It can be found in: **Timeline** > **Playback** > **Sync**

[image]